# Maximum length of Json value in postgresql 10

Tags: json, postgresql

Suppose I have the following data

```
WITH test(id, data) AS (
  VALUES
    (1, '{"key1": "Some text"}'::jsonb),
    (2, '{"other_key": "Some longer text"}'::jsonb),
    (3, '{"key_3": "Short"}'::jsonb)
)
select ??? from test;
```

Note that the JSON data is simple key-value data. The key can be anything, the value is always a String.

I want to return the maximum number of characters of the value field. 16 in this case, `select length('Some longer text')`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to turn the values into a set, then you can operate on it:

```
WITH test(id, data) AS (
  VALUES
    (1, '{"key1": "Some text"}'::jsonb),
    (2, '{"other_key": "Some longer text"}'::jsonb),
    (3, '{"key_3": "Short"}'::jsonb)
)
select max(length(t.val))
from test, jsonb_each_text(data) as t(k,val);
```